# Read text file and create a 2d array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a text file which includes student names an grades. I am trying to read the grades and put them into a 2d array in a separate method, then I want to call it in the main method to print out the array. However, if I debug my code in its own method, I get everything print out, but if I call it in the main method, then only the last row of the array got printed out. Can you guys please tell me what am I missing here?

### Thanks a lot for all your help.

This is my text file:

```
John  25 5 4.5 5 4 5 10 10 6 9.5 5.5
Jim   25 5 4 5 4.5 5 10 4 10 9.5 7.5
Kathy 15 1 3 2 1 1.5 8 2 4 3 4
Steve 21 5 3 2 1 4 5 6 7 8 8
Stacy 15 5 1 1 1 5 3 8 9 5 7
Faith 16 3 4 2 4 4 7 5 2 3 8
```

---

This is my method

```
    public static double[][] processGrades(double[][] grade) throws IOException 
{       
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Output.txt"));

        Scanner readNum = null;
        Scanner scan =  null;
        int count = 0;
        int count2 = 0;   
        int width = 0;              
        String[] col = null;                
        String[][] tempGrade = null; 
        String line = null;
        String line2 = null;
        String[] newline = null;
        int maxInLine = 0;

        try
        {           
             //Create Grades Array

             scan = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));

             scan.nextLine();

             while(scan.hasNext())
             {
                line2 = scan.nextLine();    
                col = line2.split(" ");
                width = col.length;
                count++;    

                System.out.println(col.length);
             }

             tempGrade = new String[count][width];          
             grade = new double[count][width];

             readNum =  new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));

             readNum.nextLine();

             //fill Grades array
             for (int i = 0; i < grade.length && readNum.hasNextLine(); i++) 
             {              
                   for (int j = 0; j < grade.length && readNum.hasNextLine(); j++) 
                   {    
                           tempGrade[i][j] = readNum.nextLine();    

                           String tempNum = tempGrade[i][j].replaceAll("[^0-9.0 +$]","");

                            // get the lines

                            String[] lines = tempNum.split("\\r?\\n");

                            // get the max amt of nums in a single line

                            for (String x : lines)                        
                            {
                                String[] temp = x.split("\\s+"); 

                                // split on whitespace
                                if (temp.length > maxInLine) 
                                {
                                    maxInLine = temp.length;    

                                }
                            }

                            String[][] array = new String[lines.length][maxInLine]; // declare and instantiate the array of arrays

                            for (int o = 0; o < lines.length; o++) 
                               {    
                                // split on whitespace
                                   String[] temp = lines[o].split("\\s+"); 

                                        for (int f = 1; f < maxInLine; f++) 
                                        {
                                            array[o][f] = (temp[f]);

                                            grade[o][f] = Double.parseDouble(array[o][f]);


                                        }                   
                               }    

                       }    

                }

            readNum.close();
            scan.close();
            writer.close();

        }

        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");

        }

        return grade;  
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException 
{

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("Output.txt"));

    String[] names = null;
    double[][] grades = null;   
    double[][] grade = null;
    double[][] min =null;
    double[][] max =null;
    double average =0;

    grades = processGrades(grade);

    for(int i=0; i < grades.length; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j < grades[i].length; j++)
        {
            System.out.println(grades[i][j]);
        }
    }

    writer.close();
```

### }

As you can see, only the last set of grades is printed, the rest displayed as 0.
Output:

```
16.0
3.0
4.0
2.0
4.0
4.0
7.0
5.0
2.0
3.0
8.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
0.0
```

---

Please forgive me if the format of the post is hard to read or not right. This is my first time posting question, not sure what need to be done. Thanks

Comment: Sorry but... it's a mess :-) Use the reight abstractions. Use good names on things. Your file represents a list of students, which have grades. So use a List<Student>, where Student is a class with a name field of type String, and a grades field of type double[]. Split your code into small methods, doing simple things, like parsing one line into a Student, called in a loop by another method parsing all lines into a List<Student>. Declare variables only when you need them, and not all at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Is it required that you use a standard array? You may have a better time if you consider using a collection of some sort.

Comment: @JB Nizet - I know it looks really long, but when I read the file, it seems the whole line get read as 1. I am trying to separate the string name with double grades but it won't work. The only way I can make it work and know how is to keep splitting the lines. If you know a better way, I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: @hb22 - I did not learn about collection yet.

Comment: You must split the lines. But you're not forced to put all the code in a giant method. As I said in my previous comment: you should have a separate method which parses (or splits, if you prefer) just one line and create a Student. And another one that loops through the lines and creates a list of students (or an array or students) by calling the first method for each line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to hard code the size for double array, and it works. This is my updated solution.

```
public static void main(String[] arg) throws IOException {
    double[][] grades = null;
    double[][] gradelist = Grade(grades);

    for(int i=0; i < gradelist.length; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j < gradelist[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.println(gradelist[i][j]);
        }
    }
}

public static double[][]Grade(double[][]grade) {
    Scanner in  = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("input.txt"));         
        in.nextLine();

          int rows = 6;
          int columns = 12;

          grade = new double[rows][columns];

          while(in.hasNextLine())  {
             for (int i=0; i< grade.length; i++) {
                String[] line = in.nextLine().trim().split(" ");
                for (int j = 1; j < line.length; j++) {
                   grade[i][j] = Double.parseDouble((line[j]));
                }
             }
          }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }

    return grade;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you consider the following approach. It strays quite a bit from your current code but, in my opinion, is much cleaner:

> 1) Create a class that constructs a student

```
public class Student {
private String name;
private List<Double> grades; // can be a list of int depending on what you need

public Student(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    grades = new ArrayList<Double>();
}

public void setGrade(Double grade) {
    grades.add(grade);
}


@Override
private String toString() {
    //Override what is automatically printed when you call Student.toString() to print
}
}
```

Here we have created a student abstraction.

> 2) A different file reading approach:

```
public static List<Student> load(String file) throws IOException {
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file));
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.isEmpty()) {
            ArrayList<String> partsOfLine = splitOnSpace(line);
            Student s = new Student(partsOfLine.get(0));
            /* Here, if the number of grades is consistently n, simply use
               s.setGrade(partsOfLine.get(1));
               .
               . 
               s.setGrade(partsOfLine.get(n));
            if not, use some sort of looping to set all grades */
            students.add(s)
        }
    }
return students; // This arrayList can be passed to your print method
}

 public static ArrayList<String> splitOnSpace(String line){
        String[] splits = line.split(" ");
        return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(splits));
}
```

> 3) Sample print method in main

```
public void print(List<Students> students){
for (Student s: students) {
    System.out.println(s.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: @ht22 - I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: @ht22 - I tried your method and keep getting error on this line List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(file)); I have to change to ArrayList<String> but then it doesn't return anything.

I am able to figure out a different way to make it work. Thanks a lot for trying.

Comment: @Thi hmm, I am unable to reproduce this error. Anyways, glad you found a fix.

Comment: @ht22 - yes, I see so many post here using List<String> but I can't. I am using eclipse, not sure that's the cause.

Comment: @Thi List is higher in the collections hierarchy than ArrayList so make sure you are importing List instead of ArrayList. This way you can use either a List declaration or ArrayList. Be careful, though. Even if you declare a list you must instantiate it with something like an ArrayList.